# how to connect the velodyne HDL-64 to ROS-indigo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]
This is ip addresses infromation of HDL-64E_S3.

```
 ROS version: indigo
 Laser Moudle: velodyne HDL-64E_S3

I follow the tutorial to set the IP address information.
```

[link text (http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20HDL-32E)

$sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-velodyne

$sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.43

$sudo route add 192.168.XX.YY eth0
I don't know how to define  the XX and YY. I don't have the CD which have this information.
Below this picture is my use wireshark interface.[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279346/how-to-connect-the-velodyne-hdl-64-to-ros-indigo?/) by [summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31948/summer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

In place of XX.YY, put in 3.43

Hope this solves your issue.

---

Originally posted by [aditya369007](https://answers.ros.org/users/30739/aditya369007/) with karma: 18 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0